# Mocking methods that return generics and primitives with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito

I'm trying to mock a class using Mockito 1.9.5 but I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work.

```
public class Property<T> {
    private T value;
    public T get() { return this.value; }
    public void set(T value) { this.value = value; }
}

public class Model {
    private final Property<Integer> count = new Property<Integer>();
    public Property<Integer> count() { return this.count; }
}

public class View {
    public View(Model model) {
        Integer count = model.count().get();
    }
}
```

I wrote my test boilerplate:

```
Model model = mock(Model.class, Mockito.RETURNS_MOCKS);
View view = new View(model);
```

... and got a long `ClassCastException`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$Enhancer
>
> ByMockitoWithCGLIB$$cb6ca60b cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

I know that Mockito can't mock `final` classes or primitives, but I'm at a loss for what I need to do to make this work.

Comment: I guess it doesn't work because `model.count().get()` returns `Object`, not `Integer`. You probably need to mock `count` and inject it into `Model`.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov The trouble is that I have many properties on my `Model` class, and it's very time-consuming to write mocks for all of them. I thought the point of a mocking framework was to save me from writing tons of boilerplate by hand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic type of your class `Property<Integer>` is erased during compilation. Mockito can only pick up the runtime type of your erased method. To Mockito, your class looks something like this:

```
public class Property {
  private Object value;
  public Object get() { return this.value; }
  public void set(Object value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

When you mock this class, your call to `model.count().get()` is implicitly cast to `Integer` where this instruction is added by *javac* due to your generic information. However, Mockito only returns a mock of an `Object` type after it observed the types above, thus the exception. Instead of

```
mock(Model.class, Mockito.RETURNS_MOCKS);
```

define the return value explicitly

```
mock(Model.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS); // intermediate mocks
when(model.count().get()).thenReturn(0);
```

The `Integer` type is final and cannot be mocked which is why you need to return a dummy value.

Comment: I get a `NullPointerException` on `when(model.count().get()).thenReturn(0);`. If I switch to `Model model = mock(Model.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);` then it runs without an exception. Having to manually specify dummy properties is still very tedious though.

Comment: You need to mock the intermediate class, see my updated answer. Mockito has no way of knowing that this class should be an integer as the type is erased. This is a simple limitation of Java's type system and there is nothing to do with it. And even if it knew that, Mockito could not mock the `Integer`.